# Connection Reset Error AxisFault

Tags: ssl, ibm, websphere, axis

I'm trying to call a third party web service using axis2. It was working fine before the third party provider made some changes on their server. They disabled TLS 1.0 protocol and the server only accepts **TLS 1.1** and **TLS 1.2**.

I already added the code below but still no luck.

```
try {
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        context.init(null, null, null);
        SSLContext.setDefault(context);
} catch (Exception e) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage());
}
```

Please see below error log:

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Connection reset
at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisRequestEntity.writeRequest(AxisRequestEntity.java:98)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.writeRequestBody(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:499)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2114)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.executeMethod(AbstractHTTPSender.java:621)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:193)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:75)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:404)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:231)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:443)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:406)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
at com.transactium.www.ws.mybills.payments.OnlinePaymentsStub.prepareForPayment(OnlinePaymentsStub.java:638)
at mt.com.smartutilities.mybills.ws.MyBillsInternal.myBillsPrepareForPayment(MyBillsInternal.java:627)
at mt.com.smartutilities.mybills.ws.MyBillsInternal.unpaidBillsPrepareForPayment(MyBillsInternal.java:313)
at mt.com.smartutilities.mybills.json.MyBillsJSONGatewayServlet.doGet(MyBillsJSONGatewayServlet.java:49)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:718)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1694)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:970)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:508)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3994)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:945)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:191)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:454)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:516)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:307)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:278)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1662)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:179)
at com.ibm.jsse2.b.a(b.java:192)
at com.ibm.jsse2.b.a(b.java:10)
at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:495)
at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.h(SSLSocketImpl.java:552)
at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:651)
at com.ibm.jsse2.k.write(k.java:31)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:76)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:134)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisRequestEntity.writeRequest(AxisRequestEntity.java:94)
... 44 more

[7/4/18 16:39:09:626 CEST] 00000036 MyBillsIntern E   Connection reset
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Connection reset
at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisRequestEntity.writeRequest(AxisRequestEntity.java:98)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.writeRequestBody(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:499)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2114)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.executeMethod(AbstractHTTPSender.java:621)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:193)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:75)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:404)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:231)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:443)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:406)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
at com.transactium.www.ws.mybills.payments.OnlinePaymentsStub.prepareForPayment(OnlinePaymentsStub.java:638)
at mt.com.smartutilities.mybills.ws.MyBillsInternal.myBillsPrepareForPayment(MyBillsInternal.java:627)
at mt.com.smartutilities.mybills.ws.MyBillsInternal.unpaidBillsPrepareForPayment(MyBillsInternal.java:313)
at mt.com.smartutilities.mybills.json.MyBillsJSONGatewayServlet.doGet(MyBillsJSONGatewayServlet.java:49)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:718)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1694)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:970)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:508)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3994)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:945)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:191)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:454)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:516)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:307)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:278)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1662)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:179)
at com.ibm.jsse2.b.a(b.java:192)
at com.ibm.jsse2.b.a(b.java:10)
at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:495)
at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.h(SSLSocketImpl.java:552)
at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:651)
at com.ibm.jsse2.k.write(k.java:31)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:76)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:134)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisRequestEntity.writeRequest(AxisRequestEntity.java:94)
... 44 more

[7/4/18 16:39:09:633 CEST] 00000036 MyBillsIntern E   org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Connection reset
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Connection reset
at mt.com.smartutilities.mybills.ws.MyBillsInternal.myBillsPrepareForPayment(MyBillsInternal.java:633)
at mt.com.smartutilities.mybills.ws.MyBillsInternal.unpaidBillsPrepareForPayment(MyBillsInternal.java:313)
at mt.com.smartutilities.mybills.json.MyBillsJSONGatewayServlet.doGet(MyBillsJSONGatewayServlet.java:49)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:718)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1694)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:970)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:508)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3994)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:945)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:191)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:454)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:516)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:307)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:278)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1662)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Connection reset
at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisRequestEntity.writeRequest(AxisRequestEntity.java:98)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.writeRequestBody(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:499)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2114)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.executeMethod(AbstractHTTPSender.java:621)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:193)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:75)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:404)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:231)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:443)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:406)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
at com.transactium.www.ws.mybills.payments.OnlinePaymentsStub.prepareForPayment(OnlinePaymentsStub.java:638)
at mt.com.smartutilities.mybills.ws.MyBillsInternal.myBillsPrepareForPayment(MyBillsInternal.java:627)
... 27 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:179)
at com.ibm.jsse2.b.a(b.java:192)
at com.ibm.jsse2.b.a(b.java:10)
at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:495)
at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.h(SSLSocketImpl.java:552)
at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:651)
at com.ibm.jsse2.k.write(k.java:31)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:76)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:134)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisRequestEntity.writeRequest(AxisRequestEntity.java:94)
... 44 more
```

The application is deployed on IBM WAS. Please see below server specification:

WebSphere Platform 7.0.0.37 [ND 7.0.0.37 cf371506.01]
Host Operating System is AIX, version 7.1
Java version = 1.6.0, Java Compiler = j9jit24, Java VM name = IBM J9 VM

Answer (score 0):

That's a really old version of Java and of WebSphere (in fact, now [out of support](https://www-01.ibm.com/software/support/lifecycleapp/PLCDetail.wss?q45=S913706N13920K48)), but it does appear TLS 1.1 and 1.2 should be available there:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27005002#WAS70

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21575620

I wonder if setting the QoS options in WebSphere will resolve this. I don't have access to a 7.0 server, and I can't seem to find any 7.0 documentation online any longer, but the 8.5.5 settings are described here:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/csec_sslconfigs.html

Where the `sslProtocol` option is what I'm thinking of. Even with earlier versions of WAS 8.5.5, that's set to a default value that doesn't do newer TLS.